# CSS display: table-caption

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I set my  element to display: table-caption in CSS: It brings it next to the label. Is there a way to keep it at the bottom?

```css
input, #number{
  display: table-cell;
}
#examples{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group  col-md-6">
<label class="input-group-addon" id="number">Number</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required></input>
<ul id="examples">
    <li>111 111</li>
    <li> 11 11 11</li>
</ul>

</div>

<div class="input-group  col-md-6">
<label class="input-group-addon" id="number">Postal code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required></input>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need the `table-caption` exactly?

Comment: Why you don't put your `<label>` and your `<input>` before you close the `</div>` ?  HTML is an interpreted language, it reads elements line by line so if you want it to be at the end of the `<div>` you have to put it just before closing it.

Comment: Because that's exactly what its supposed to do.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Do you want to have that #examples div below the #number div?

Comment: I deleted the table-caption but still have a problem

Comment: @Nes no below the input

Comment: "*I deleted the table-caption but still have a problem*" - Thats probably because you are using inappropriate styling. Why are you using table-cell?

Comment: I tried that and found out there will be a problem when I add one more input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why a table layout is needed here, but `table-caption` can go along with [`caption-side`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side)

> The `caption-side` CSS property puts the content of a table's `<caption>` on the specified side. The values are relative to the `writing-mode` of the table.

```css
input,
#number {
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group {
 /* display:table; *//* or table-row can be set here if needed */
}

#examples {
  background: red;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group  col-md-6">
<label class="input-group-addon" id="number">Number</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required/>
<ul id="examples">
    <li>111 111</li>
    <li> 11 11 11</li>
</ul>

</div>

<div class="input-group  col-md-6">
<label class="input-group-addon" id="number">Postal code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required/>
</div>
```